# Ubuntu - Problem with SCP / Git / Rsync

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, scp

I'm having a really weird problem.  For some reason, I can't scp, rsync, git pull or git push files larger than 1406 bytes.  I can clone an entire repo no problem.  I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.  I've exhausted all the cut and paste solutions for other users experiencing the same issues.  Anyone have ideas?

System: 
Ubuntu 11.04 desktop

Tried:

- Altering MTU
- This solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=891695&page=2
- Reinstalling openssh-client completely

Still no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bizarre problems it's always a good idea to start a really broad process of elimination.

See if it can be narrowed down to either a hardware or software problem:

1. Try booting with a Ubuntu boot CD - see if you can reproduce the problem
2. Try plugging your hard drive into a different system - see if the problem still occurs

If it's software, you can either reinstall or start troubleshooting. If it's hardware you can start swapping out parts, like the network card/chipset or RAM.

By making smart choices in what you test, you can - if not solve the problem - find a good workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite likely a hardware problem

There are many routers/switches with a maximum packet size. See whether you can enable jumbo frames (ethtool or see e.g. [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-debian-ubuntu-jumbo-frames-configuration/))

You could /should try what limits you run into with netcat and tools like that. I'm sure there will be instant network testing utils toolkits floating around